# Applescript: Activate application which belongs to the window under the mouse cursor

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to use applescript to tell to which application the window under the cursor belongs and then activate that application?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea that would result in chaos. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make the application under the cursor active, but I don't want to  use a left click because that could cause additional things to happen.

Comment: Why are you trying to make the application under the cursor active? The user would have had to double-click your applescript application first, which would be a file in your Finder, which would make the Finder active. It just sounds like a terrible idea. What are you **actually** trying to achieve? What is your **intent**?